# jsf - Restrict access to specific * .xhtml pages from url

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I am doing a project with jsf and I want to restrict access to users on specific pages .xhtml from url and I do not know how to do it.
The goal is that if the user enters the url that takes them to these pages, do not let them access them.

Comment: Use a [filter](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

Comment: But better to use something like PicketLink (or similar) and not create a homegrown thing (if you have a question like this now, the chance is you unconsciously introduce security risks)

Comment: Apache Shiro would also be an option.